# Sorting data by groups in Excel

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

So, I've looked around and tried to solve this on my own. This isn't an absolutely crucial question currently, I just want to know if it could be done.

So let's say I've got a list with some data that looks like

```
Date      Location 
01/24/14  H-12
01/25/14  BB-44
01/30/14  G-12
01/29/14  7A-55
01/28/14  NN-15
01/24/14  GG-47
```

What I want is to be able to sort the data by Location, but I don't want it to be the general way, otherwise I'll end up with 7A-55, BB-44, G-12, H-12, NN-15. I want the data to be sorted so that double letters and single letters are sorted together. E.G. it should be G-12, H-12, BB-44, NN-15, 7A-55 once everything has been sorted.

I've tried creating a custom list sort, but it doesn't work. the way intended. The custom list I tried was A-Z, AA-ZZ, 7A (items were listed out, but for saving space I wrote them like that).

Like I said, this isn't a particularly huge deal if it can't be done, it just would have made it a little easier.

**Edit 1** Here is what I would like to be the output

```
Date      Location
01/30/12  G-12
01/24/14  H-12
01/25/14  BB-44
01/24/14  GG-47
01/28/14  NN-15
01/29/14  7A-55
```

### Edit

All of these worked in the regards i wanted to, although if I had to choose a favorite it would be the base 36 number conversion one. That was some real out-of-the-box thinking and the math geek in me appreciated it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Yeah let me edit it really quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it works, but is a bit complex, so rather just for fun:
This UDF returns a value that can be used as sort key. It transforms the code into a four-digit base 36-number, i.e. using A-Z and 0-9 as symbols (like hex uses 0-9 and A-F). To get at your desired output, I literally put the symbols in this order, letters first (so "A" = 0 and "0" = 26). 
(The missing 'digits' are filled up with zeros, which are in this case "A"s)
It works ;)

```
Public Function Base36Transform(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, c As String
    Dim v
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rv As Long

    v = Split(r.Text, "-")
    s1 = v(0)
    s2 = v(1)
    s = Right("A" & s1, 2) & Right("A" & s2, 2)
    rv = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, Len(s) - i + 1, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            rv = rv + (Val(c) + 26) * (36 ^ (i - 1))
        Else
            ' c is like "[A-Z]"
            rv = rv + (Asc(c) - Asc("A")) * (36 ^ (i - 1))
        End If
    Next
    Base36Transform = rv
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to add the function definition, but it gives me an error. I tried to add my own function and same thing. I'll restart and let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hm, put the function in a new module, not the worksheet module. Just one point it might be...

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is often a very creative process. VBA can ease up the process, but a little extension of the data will work just as well.

See my results:

[image]

The way I did it is by getting the length of each string, just to be safe. This is gotten by simply going `=LEN(B2)`, dragged down.

Then I check if it starts with `7`. If it does, assign `1`, otherwise keep at `0`. I used this formula: `=(LEFT(B2,1)="7")*1`, dragged down.

Now, my custom sort is this:

[image]

Now I might have gotten some things wrong here, or I might even have done overkill by going the `Length` column. However, the logic is pretty much what you're aiming for.

Hope this helps in a way! Let us know. :)

Comment: Is there no way to do it via JUST the location colulmn?, also I'm fairly familiar with VBA, so if that would be easier then I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little lazy here and assuming your data sits in Column A,B.  You mightneed to adjust your range or the starting point of your list.  But here's the code:

```
Sub sortttttt()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Range("B2").Activate
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Value = Len(ActiveCell.Value) & ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop

Set rng = Range("A1:B6")
rng.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Range("B2").Activate
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Value = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Just saw your update.  The element 7A-55 will be in front of other double letters.  Let me know if that's an issue, thanks

Comment: not really. I'm just trying to divide the vehicles we inspect based on their yard location. My yard has 2 sides, single letters on one and double/7A/7B on the other. It would just mean we ignore the top part of the list until we get to the double letter side

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  In that case the code should do the trick, or if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in columns B:C with labels in Row1 and no intervening blank rows, add a column with:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(C2))),3,IF(FIND("-",C2)>2,2,1))
```

in D1 copied down to suit and sort ascending Location within sort ascending of the added column.