# Sorting Data before print in Excel VBA doesn't always work

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

### Background Info

I've got a list with roughly 7 columns. The 7th column is a special column I use to sort the data. I have an onBeforePrint sub that runs, sorting the list by that last column, and then hiding it before it is printed.

The Problem is that sometimes it works and everything gets sorted correctly, sometimes it doesn't. Also, when it does work all of the values in the last column show an error of #!Value before I click on them. when I click on them, they generally (not always) change back, but when they don't change back the sort no longer works. Any Ideas?

### Code

Part of this code was grabbed via the Record Macro button, the other part I added on my own. (Namely the EntireColumn.Hidden parts)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    
        
    ActiveSheet.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=6, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    
End Sub
```

#### The Function

This function is what the last cell will equal. It takes in a value such as "A-7", "HH-7", "BB-31", "7A-14" and converts them to base 36 in order to sort them so that all single letters and all double letters are sorted by different groups. This code comes from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462233/sorting-data-by-groups-in-excel/21463346?noredirect=1).

```
Public Function Base36Transform(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, c As String
    Dim v
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rv As Long

    v = Split(r.text, "-")
    s1 = v(0)
    s2 = v(1)
    s = Right("A" & s1, 2) & Right("A" & s2, 2)
    rv = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, Len(s) - i + 1, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            rv = rv + (Val(c) + 10) * (36 ^ (i - 1))
        Else
            ' c is like "[A-Z]"
            rv = rv + (Asc(c) - Asc("A")) * (36 ^ (i - 1))
        End If
    Next
    Base36Transform = rv
End Function
```

Any Help is appreciated. As soon as the internet at my job stops screwing up I'll post a screenshot of what I mean by the #VALUE thing

Comment: try to add `ActiveSheet.Range("G:G").Calculate` before sorting

Comment: Nope, same thing. Sorts fine, but once everything has been sorted the #VALUE! error appears. Sometimes when I click on it, it gets fixed, other times it doesn't. Tried putting your suggestion both before and after

Comment: You can send me your code and data via email and I will take a look at it for you

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that as it's a company thing and I'm fairly certain it would break disclosure if i I did. Thanks for the help though!